# PHP session expires but after page refresh I'm not redirected

Tags: php, .htaccess, session, model-view-controller

Problem is, when my session expires I have to reload page twice to get back to login page.
here is my .htaccess file

```
php_flag display_errors on
php_value error_reporting 9999

RewriteEngine On
Options -MultiViews
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 5
php_value session.gc_divisor 1
php_value session.gc_probability 1
php_value session.cookie_lifetime 5
php_value session.save_path /path/to/session/folder

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I'm using some custom MVC framework and I'm calling handleLogin() function in controllers  __construct function

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    Auth::handleLogin();
}
```

And finally here is handleLogin() function

```
public static function handleLogin() {
    @session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['loggedIn'])) {
        $logged = $_SESSION['loggedIn'];
    } else {
        session_destroy();
        header('location: ' . URL . 'login');
        exit;
    }
}
```

What do I need to change to redirect user to Login page after FIRST refresh when session expires?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I'm running it on Debian

UPDATE: here is logout function and it works fine, when user clicks it he is immidiately redirected to login page

```
function logout()
{
    session_destroy;
    header('location: ' . URL .  'login');
    exit;
}
```

UPDATE #2 I got some screenshots for better problem description

1) When session is active and everything works fine
[image]

2) session expired - user clicks link or refresh page (after first refresh)
as you can notice in firebug login is loaded but it's not shown
[image]

3) after 2nd refresh
[image]

One more thing is.. when using default **php.ini settings** (session lifetime: 1440 sec) everthing works fine with no problem in redirecting

Comment: Can you show us the code that you've got in place to expire a session?

Comment: Hello friend, first of all thanks for your time! I'm not sure if I understood your question but session expiration time is set via .htaccess file `php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 5`. I don't have any particular code that checks if session expired or not. Do I have to check it manually? I thought gc_maxlifetime will do the job..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what caused error, but I'm not exactly sure why was it causing such a stupid bug.
I had `session_set_cookie_params(0);` earlier in my code, and while my browser was opened all the time i changed my code, removed `session_set_cookie_params(0);` and added `php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 5`. That's what caused conflict. One side expected session to last until browser closes and other side terminated session after 5 sec. I cleared my cache 100 times and nothing happened until i closed my browser and reopened project again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to create a logout function where you have to write session destroy and then redirect. so when user clicks his logout link then you can destroy his session variables and then redirect to login page again.

If you are using ajax callback to destroy session then you have to refresh the page in javascript to redirect user to login page

Comment: it's not problem in logout, logout works fine, but when user is inactive and session expires and for example he comes back and press F5, he is not redirected to login page, he needs to press F5 again to get back to login page.

Comment: in this case you must check the session on every ajax request if the session expired you must have logic to display login popup again.

Comment: strange thing just happened, I did nothing since yesterday on my project and today i reopened it and everything works as it should. And btw since im using MVC every ajax call is goin through controller which checks if session is active or not